# Notepad++ lost favorites

Tags: notepad++

I have the latest ver of Notepad++ 8.3.2 64 bit on Win 11.
I already set up my favorites with the list of folders, files and sessions that worked fine for a long time.

Today, without any particular reason(there is no update or change anywhere), when I open the notepad++, I receive an error saying that Notepad++ doesn't find `favorites.dat` file. Now my favorite section is completely empty :-(

I found in the following folder and an empty `favorites.dat` file:

C:\Users<my username>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config

I don't have a way to restore the above file...

Anyway to restore my favorites?

Update: npp-explorer-plugin settings:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there are backups of that file unfortunately. For the next time you can sync it to the cloud with a symlink.

Comment: Is the path I mentioned is the correct one?

Comment: You are referring to the `npp-explorer-plugin`?

Comment: yes. Anyway, I found in the plugin settings that the path is correct.  I add an screenshot to the question